# bash alias assignment in .bashrc for specific date command

Tags: bash, date, alias, gnu

I am trying to set an alias to show value of specific date command.  When I set the alias, I get correct value, but also get "command not found..."  Is there a way to set this without the error?

**Summary:**

I am trying to get last day of previous month for the current day.  Todays date is: 20210221

I am using the following command to get the date I want:

```
  
date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day" +%Y%m%d
20210131
```

**Results:**

I set alias for this in .bashrc

```
[root@centos_8_1 ~]# alias | grep date
alias test_date='$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day" +%Y%m%d)'
```

When I try to call, I get the correct value, but also get "command not found...

```
[root@centos_8_1 ~]# test_date
bash: 20210131: command not found...
```

**Questions:**

Am I missing something with syntax?

How can I set an alias for this date?

What is the command that is not found?

First time poster, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

An alias is simply a way to replace some string at the start of a command with some other arbitrary string. What's happening in your case is that `test_date` is replaced with `$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day" +%Y%m%d)`, which first runs a `date` command and then tries to run the resulting [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution), resulting in "executing" the date string.

The solution is to simply remove the `$()` surrounding the alias string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I removed the first parentheses and it worked.